# Why is it bad practice to call ref.read inside the provider body?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I am new to Riverpod and I dont get why it is considered bad practice to do this:

```
final myProvider = Provider((ref) {
// Bad practice to call `read` here
final value = ref.read(anotherProvider);
});
```

Why is this better:

```
final repositoryProvider = Provider((ref) => Repository(ref));

class Repository {
Repository(this.ref);

final ProviderRefBase ref;
}
```

[Link to source](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers)

Comment: As far as i under stand, ref.read is on demand, reads value once at the point of invocation, hence it's recommended not to use it. Advice to use ref.read in callback/onpressed use cases. Below threads might help your for better understanding>
https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/864
https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#using-refread-to-obtain-the-state-of-a-provider-once